# Iterate over JSON data to make into a table Groovy

Tags: json, api, groovy

I have created an API wrapper for import.io that brings me back some data. I am looking to create a table of the data so it displays the football league on my website. I am struggling to see how I would iterate over the data and transform it into a table in Groovy. I am currently using the JsonSlurper to get the data from the API into JSON. Here is my JSON

```
{
    "extractorData": {
        "data": [
            {
                "group": [
                    {
                        "Content": [
                            {
                                "text": "Clapham Junction Thursday"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 1": [
                            {
                                "text": "P"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 2": [
                            {
                                "text": "W"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 3": [
                            {
                                "text": "D"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 4": [
                            {
                                "text": "L"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 5": [
                            {
                                "text": "GF"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 6": [
                            {
                                "text": "GA"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 7": [
                            {
                                "text": "GD"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 8": [
                            {
                                "text": "PTS"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Content": [
                            {
                                "text": "Wavey Wanderers"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Link": [
                            {
                                "href": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/TeamProfile.aspx?TeamId=2865&LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61&DivisionId=1098",
                                "text": "Wavey Wanderers"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 1": [
                            {
                                "text": "5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 2": [
                            {
                                "text": "3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 3": [
                            {
                                "text": "0"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 4": [
                            {
                                "text": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 5": [
                            {
                                "text": "31"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 6": [
                            {
                                "text": "22"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 7": [
                            {
                                "text": "9"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 8": [
                            {
                                "text": "9"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Content": [
                            {
                                "text": "The Feet of Hermes"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Link": [
                            {
                                "href": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/TeamProfile.aspx?TeamId=2206&LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61&DivisionId=1098",
                                "text": "The Feet of Hermes"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 1": [
                            {
                                "text": "5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 2": [
                            {
                                "text": "3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 3": [
                            {
                                "text": "0"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 4": [
                            {
                                "text": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 5": [
                            {
                                "text": "21"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 6": [
                            {
                                "text": "13"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 7": [
                            {
                                "text": "8"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 8": [
                            {
                                "text": "9"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Content": [
                            {
                                "text": "Multiple Scoregasms"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Link": [
                            {
                                "href": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/TeamProfile.aspx?TeamId=959&LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61&DivisionId=1098",
                                "text": "Multiple Scoregasms"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 1": [
                            {
                                "text": "5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 2": [
                            {
                                "text": "3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 3": [
                            {
                                "text": "0"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 4": [
                            {
                                "text": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 5": [
                            {
                                "text": "25"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 6": [
                            {
                                "text": "24"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 7": [
                            {
                                "text": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 8": [
                            {
                                "text": "9"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Content": [
                            {
                                "text": "Pugh let the Cruyffs out"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Link": [
                            {
                                "href": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/TeamProfile.aspx?TeamId=2875&LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61&DivisionId=1098",
                                "text": "Pugh let the Cruyffs out"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 1": [
                            {
                                "text": "5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 2": [
                            {
                                "text": "3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 3": [
                            {
                                "text": "0"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 4": [
                            {
                                "text": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 5": [
                            {
                                "text": "17"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 6": [
                            {
                                "text": "20"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 7": [
                            {
                                "text": "-3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 8": [
                            {
                                "text": "9"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Content": [
                            {
                                "text": "Michu At De Gea Ba"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Link": [
                            {
                                "href": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/TeamProfile.aspx?TeamId=2656&LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61&DivisionId=1098",
                                "text": "Michu At De Gea Ba"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 1": [
                            {
                                "text": "5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 2": [
                            {
                                "text": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 3": [
                            {
                                "text": "0"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 4": [
                            {
                                "text": "3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 5": [
                            {
                                "text": "20"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 6": [
                            {
                                "text": "20"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 7": [
                            {
                                "text": "0"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 8": [
                            {
                                "text": "6"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Content": [
                            {
                                "text": "Shire Soldiers"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Link": [
                            {
                                "href": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/TeamProfile.aspx?TeamId=1994&LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61&DivisionId=1098",
                                "text": "Shire Soldiers"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 1": [
                            {
                                "text": "5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 2": [
                            {
                                "text": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 3": [
                            {
                                "text": "0"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 4": [
                            {
                                "text": "4"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 5": [
                            {
                                "text": "17"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 6": [
                            {
                                "text": "32"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 7": [
                            {
                                "text": "-15"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Value 8": [
                            {
                                "text": "3"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "resourceId": "7103552b590f38e1b6c50352145431ac",
        "url": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/Standings.aspx?LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61"
    },
    "pageData": {
        "resourceId": "7103552b590f38e1b6c50352145431ac",
        "statusCode": 200,
        "timestamp": 1485378614012
    },
    "runtimeConfigId": "cfc5c9d6-2799-4eec-a899-d18fbd53db97",
    "sequenceNumber": -1,
    "timestamp": 1485378824648,
    "url": "http://london5aside.spawtz.com/SpawtzSkin/Fixtures/Standings.aspx?LeagueId=28&SeasonId=61"
}
```

Here is what I currently do in my Ratpack handler

```
class LeagueTableHandler extends InjectionHandler {
    void handle(Context context, ImportClient importClient) {
        def data = importClient.leagueDataExtractor()
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data.contentAsString)
        context.render Jackson.json(jsonSlurper)
    }
}
```

And ideally I'd like it to look like this

[image: json screenshot]
Does anyone have any tips when it comes to processing Json like this?

EDIT

I am not sure if its the JSON structure that's causing me issues, but the only way I've managed to get the values in my tests is by doing this.

```
 List<String> teamNames = []

        when:
         jsonSlurped.result.extractorData.data.group.Content.text.each { firstNested ->
            firstNested.each { secondNested ->
                secondNested.each { finalValue ->
                    teamNames.add(finalValue)
                }
            }
        }
```

Obviously I'd rather not do this for Value 1, Value 2 etc, is there a better more effcient way to grab each piece of info?

Comment: What format do you need for the UI component? That's what going to drive your back end code

Comment: Just a standard html table

Comment: You're using groovy templates for the UI?

Comment: Sorry I am using handlebars

Comment: I was thinking possibly mapping each object inside the group array to an object, store these objects in a list and then iterate over in handlebars, but couldn't see to get that approach to work